# Flash AS3 drawline displays text

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, range, line-drawing

I'm currently working on a nomograph and I was able to create 2 sliders connected with a line, but is there a way to get the line to read the middle numbers kind of like in the example below.

I'd need the line to display multiple numbers of the "Distance".

Also is it possible to have a slider display multiple numbers in different units of measure like meters/feet

**OPTION 2**

Would it be possible to have line.graphic play a movieclip or button overstate every time it passes through it?

As of now I'm thinking of using a type of enemy class, so whenever, line.graphic passes through it, it displays the number(s).

[example nomograph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNZbH.gif)

here's what i have so far...for the sliders I placed a movieclip "imageholder1" on top of another movieclip "rect"

```
var imgWidth:Number = imageHolder1.width;
var imgHeight:Number = imageHolder1.height;
var rectWidth:Number = rect.width;
var rectHeight:Number = rect.height;
var rectX:Number = rect.x;
var rectY:Number = rect.y;
var img1Width:Number = imageHolder2.width;
var img1Height:Number = imageHolder2.height;
var rect1Width:Number = rect1.width;
var rect1Height:Number = rect1.height;
var rect1X:Number = rect1.x;
var rect1Y:Number = rect1.y;
// Do math to correctly make the drag bounds using values attained above
var boundWidth = rectWidth - imgWidth;
var boundHeight = rectHeight - imgHeight;
var bound1Width = rect1Width - img1Width;
var bound1Height = rect1Height - img1Height;

var line:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
addChild(line);

draw(null);

imageHolder1.width = txtout.width
imageHolder1.minimum = 0;
imageHolder1.maximum = 100;
imageHolder1.value = 100;
imageHolder1.snapInterval = 2;

var sliderValues:uint = imageHolder1.y;
imageHolder1.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, sliderChanged);
function sliderChanged(evt:Event):void {
sliderValues = imageHolder1.value/100;
txtout.text = (imageHolder1.value/100).toFixed(2);
}
// Now apply the variable numbers with the math we want as bounds
var boundsRect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(rectX, rectY, 
boundWidth, boundHeight);
    // Enable drag
    imageHolder1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, DragImage1);
    function DragImage1(event:MouseEvent) {
// Here you see we apply the boundsRect when they drag
imageHolder1.startDrag(false, boundsRect);
 stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, draw);
}
// Stop drag
imageHolder1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, DropImage1);
function DropImage1(event:MouseEvent) {
imageHolder1.stopDrag();
 stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, draw);
}

 var bounds1Rect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(rect1X, rect1Y, 
bound1Width, bound1Height);
    // Enable drag
    imageHolder2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, DragImage2);
    function DragImage2(event:MouseEvent) {
    // Here you see we apply the boundsRect when they drag
imageHolder2.startDrag(false, bounds1Rect);
     stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, draw);
}
// Stop drag
imageHolder2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, DropImage2);
function DropImage2(event:MouseEvent) {
    imageHolder2.stopDrag();
     stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, draw);
}

function draw(event:Event):void{
    line.graphics.clear();
    line.graphics.lineStyle(1,1);
    line.graphics.moveTo(imageHolder1.x,imageHolder1.y);
    line.graphics.lineTo(imageHolder2.x,imageHolder2.y);
}

var sliderValue:uint = imageHolder2.y;
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void {
    sliderValue = imageHolder2.y;
    status_txt.text = "Slider position is: "+sliderValue;
}
```

**update**

So came accross this, which I'm editing to suit my needs and I was able to trace all the info in flash, and learning more about xml to flash.

But my question now is how to implement it all on to the flash stage?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<flow>
    <axis name="diameter" type="parallel" 
    scaleFunction="log(t)"> 
    <range>0.01,02, ,50</range> 
    <xposition>0.0</xposition> 
    <crop>0.032,0.977</crop> 
    <title>Diameter [in.]</title> 
    </axis>
    <axis name="weightFlow" type="parallel" 
    scaleFunction="log(t)"> 
    <range>0.001,100000</range> 
    <xposition>0.16</xposition> 
    <crop>0.127,0.941</crop> 
    <title>Weight Flow [1000 
    lb./hr.]</title> 
    </axis> 
    <axis name="massVelocity" 
    type="parallel" scaleFunction="log(t)"> 
    <range>1.0,10000</range> 
    <xposition>0.325</xposition> 
    <crop>0.091,0.91</crop> 
    <title>Mass Velocity 
    [lb./(hr.)(sq.ft.)]</title> 
    </axis> 
    <axis name="turning" type="turning"> 
    <xposition>0.48</xposition> 
    </axis> 
    <axis name="pressureDrop" 
    type="parallel" scaleFunction="log(t)"> 
    <range>0.000001,100</range> 
    <xposition>0.713</xposition> 
    <crop>0.175,0.902</crop> 
    <title>Pressure Drop 
    [lb./sq.in./ft.pipe]</title> 
    </axis> 
    <axis name="pressure" type="parallel" 
    scaleFunction="log(t)" layout="left"> 
    <range>0.001,100</range> 
    <xposition>1.0</xposition> 
    <title>Centipoises^0.16/(lb./cu.ft. 
    at 1 atm)</title> 
    </axis>
</flow>
```

Comment: What's wrong with their shown formula "Speed x Time = Distance"? This **[link](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/63338.html)** shows you how to calculate the middle value. Also this **[link](http://lalashan.mcmaster.ca/theobio/math/index.php/Nomogram)** might give a clue on calculation code. Have you got an image of **your exact nomograph**? I mean are your scales exactly like that picture?

Comment: Either you cleverly calculate the logarithmic scale or you put the notch values into a database that you query. This means maybe creating 2 arrays. `Array-1` for pixel heights of notches and `Array-2` for the notch/scale value at that height (Y pos). Then you check where your linked line intersects the line of Distance scale. That Y-pos is what you check for in `Array-1` and when you find nearest array slot with that number, its index is used in `Array-2` to get scale value.

Comment: for work reasons I can't show my nomograph...but I can say the first row on the left is

Imp. Gal, Litres, and US Gal

Then in the middle it has

mm and inches

And on the right 

meters and feet

Comment: But damn dude, really appreciate you helping me out, IF i can get it setup, calculating the logarithmic scale may be best due to the decimals. in between the notch values.

Unless there's a way to get the numbers between the notch values with the arrays?

I'm still learning flash and work has me on this project that's a bit above my head.

Comment: BTW use @VC.One so I get notifications. I'm here only cos it occured to me to re-check on your Question progress. No worries about image share. Does it look something like this **[link](http://www.ryco.com.au/index.php?id=196)**? If yes then it's a very different logic to the "example nomograph" you originally posted. It's easier cos of standard formulas for calculating pipe **diameter** vs fluid **rate** vs **velocity** (no boat knots involved ;-) here ). I'll try make you a basic demo later tonight (UK time).

Comment: @VC.One Dude that's the graph, if I could I would of uploaded it...but didn't think to look for it online. But yea man if I could get a working demo that would be awesome!

been making some progress on getting xml into flash, but then getting flash and math to work...I still got a ways to go.

I'll shoot you an e-mail at your yahoo account

Comment: @VC.One curious on how that demo is going?

Comment: I've only got a solution for calculating middle value from known (left & right) values. Yeah sorry I misread the question as meaning that _"...given three values, if I know two of them, how do I calculate the third?"_. That's what got me interested in the possible algorithm (and if there was no answer, I would try something myself). Such algorithms are needed all the time in various situations, so I didn't mind learning a new trick... Anyways on re-reading you want to convert pixel height to match some scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will show you how to calculate "Bore size" (middle value) from specified numbers of "Rate" and "Velocity". You can change `inputNum_Rate` and `inputNum_Velo`. For example, in that nomograph **[image](http://www.ryco.com.au/tl_files/RYCO/images/technical/Nomograph.JPG)** you can see they have a *flow-rate* of 100 litres/min and a *velocity* of 4.5 metres/sec. The middle value should be around 22 mm (or 0.85 to 0.89 inches?). Try both formulas to decide which you feel is more precise for your project.

The industry-standard formula for this is simply :

> **D = Q / V** (where *D* = diameter, *Q* = flow rate and *V* = *velocity*).

However to closely match your nomograph image it seems this other formula works better :

> ***Q*** = input_FlowRate x offset_of_Rate;
>  ***V*** =
>   input_Velocity x offset_of_Velocity;
>   result = ***Q*** /
>   ***V***;
>   ***result*** = Math.sqrt(4 * ***result*** / Math.PI);
>  
>   ***result*** *= 10; //# multiply by 10 for millimetres

**Demo** - Testing the numbers by code : 
Start a new project and paste the code in **Actions** panel then press **ctrl**+**enter** to debug.
 Results are shown in debugger (if you don't see text / feedback / output then try press **F2**).

In the code section "**TEST APP**"... Go to step **(2)** and change `inputNum_Rate = 100;` and `inputNum_Velo = 4.5;` to whatever units you want (as listed on your nomograph).

```
//# for: Define INPUT unit
var inputNum_Rate : Number = 0;     
var inputNum_Velo : Number = 0;

//# for: Define INPUT unit type (format)
var format_Rate : String = "ltr_pMin"; //set: "ltr_pMin" (Litres)or "gal_pMin" (Gallons)
var format_Diam : String = "mm"; //set: "mm" or "inches"
var format_Velo : String = "m_pSec"; //set: "m_pSec" (meters) or "ft_pSec" (feet)

var offset_Rate : Number = 16.66666666666666666; //Litres per Min
var offset_Velo : Number = 100.0; //Metres per Sec

var nvel : Number = 0;  var svel : Number = 0;
var nflow : Number = 0; var sflow : Number = 0;

var s : Number = 0;
var resultNum  : Number = 0; // holds the result

////////////// TEST APP /////////////////

//# 1) setup INPUT TYPE
format_Rate = "ltr_pMin"; //# Rate //set: "ltr_pMin" (Litres)or "gal_pMin" (Gallons)
format_Diam = "mm"; //# Diameter //set: "mm" or "inches"
format_Velo = "m_pSec"; //# Velocity //set: "m_pSec" (meters) or "ft_pSec" (feet)

//# 2) setup INPUT values ("Rate" & "Velocity" to get middle "Diameter");
inputNum_Rate = 100; inputNum_Velo = 4.5; //# These should be from input textbox

//# 3) calculate Diameter based on inputs of Rate & Velocity
resultNum = calculate_Diameter( inputNum_Rate, inputNum_Velo );
trace ("final :: resultNum : " + resultNum );

function calculate_Diameter( myRate:Number, myVelo:Number ) : Number
{
    //# RESET
    svel = nvel = nflow = sflow = s = resultNum = 0; //reset

    sflow = myRate * offset_Rate;
    svel = myVelo * offset_Velo;
    s = sflow/svel; //get Area
    s = Math.sqrt(4 * s / Math.PI);

    //# CONVERT
    s = s * 10;     s = Number(s.toPrecision(5));

    //# CHECK RESULTS IN DEBUGGER....
    trace("===========================================" );
    trace("\n FLOW RATE : " );
    //convert Litres and US gallons :: US-Gallons = ( litres / 3.79) || Litres = (3.79 * US-Gallons)
    trace("litres p/sec : " + ( myRate ) );
    trace("gallon p/sec : " + ( myRate / 3.79 ) );

    trace("\n BORE SIZE : " );
    //convert Mm and Inches :: (1 mm = 0.0393701 inch || 1 inch = 25.4 mm)
    trace("millms : " + (s) );
    trace("inches : " + (s * 0.0393701) );

    trace("\n VELOCITY : " );
    //convert Metres and Feet :: (1 metre= 3.28084 foot || 1 foot= 0.3048 metres)
    trace("m/sec  : " + ( myVelo ) );
    trace("ft/sec : " + ( myVelo * 3.28084 ) );
    trace("===========================================" );


    //# RETURN result of this function
    return resultNum;

}
```

Comment: Ah thanks, yea it's all gravy and mashed potatoes, I found a longer and tedious....by duplicating and renaming the same buttons over and over...satisfied with it, but it gets the job done, but I'll definitely be playing with this...see if I can turn it into a fully functioning monograph.

Thanks for the help, seriously, I'd buy you a cake or something if i could.